# How to formulate a machine learning problem?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, labeling

Virtually no books talk about how to formulate a ML problem, especially the process of creating the right label. Here I use an online hotel search portal as an example to explain my thought process and seek comments from readers. If we want to increase the overall click through rate(CTR) of the portal. Then we **should** try to build a model to **accurately** estimate the CTR for each hotel. Once we have the model, then we can sort hotels by predicted CTRs in a descending order. Since the hotels in the top positions of a search result will get more clicks, this approach in turn will increase the overall CTR of the portal.

Comment: What is a "right label"? Are you thinking about the outcome (discrete or continuous event to predict) or the predictors that may be used to predict that particular outcome? The latter are also called features in the ML literature, and there's a wide range of resources on *feature engineering*.

Comment: @chl by label, I refer to the outcome.

Comment: Although this work flow seems to make sense, none of it appears logically necessary.  Sure, it can be helpful to predict CTRs accurately -- but is it necessary to be able to predict them at all?  Don't you *really* want to know how to predict *the effects of possible interventions?* And then it's not at all evident you should be sorting the hotels by predicted CTR.  Why wouldn't putting the hotels with *lowest* predicted CTRs potentially produce an even greater in increase in overall CTR?  Such considerations suggest you ought to rethink your strategy.

Comment: @whuber My thinking is if I can predict CTR accurately for given hotel and visitor and put the hotels with the highest predicted CTRs on the top of a search query result, then in the long run this strategy will yield overall the best CTR. Can you elaborate on "effects of possible interventions"? Don't know what it is.

Comment: An intervention is something you do to improve the overall CTR.  It is conceivable--even plausible--that doing something to bring attention to the hotels with *lowest* CTRs might create the greatest improvement.  Maybe those with the highest CTRs have rates already as high as they possibly might go, for instance, whence highlighting them wouldn't accomplish anything.  The point is that you have to focus on (a) what you can do and (b) what your possible actions might accomplish.  Sometimes the intuitively obvious solution is not only poor, it can even backfire.